# How to find dictionary by date in dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, each is a boxscore of a game in a season.

If I wanted to pull one specific game by date, how would I pull that one dictionary out?

Something like:

```
for game in schedule:
    boxscore = game.boxscore if date = '2021-03-21'
```

schedule contains all the games and each game has a 'boxscore' key, inside the boxscore is all the data I am trying to access by date.

[link to API info](https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/sportsipy/nba/schedule.html#Game)
Thanks!

```py
def management(request):
    """ View to return site management page """
    schedule = Schedule('CHI')
    for game in schedule:
        boxscore = game.boxscore
        date = game.date
        date_time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a, %b %d, %Y')
        game_date = date_time_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        context = {
            'game_date': game_date,
            'boxscore': boxscore,
        }

    return render(request, 'management/management.html',
                  context)
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data? Right now it is hard to help you since it is unknown how the *structure* looks like.

Comment: updated with link and description

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  So far, you're asking us to teach to you access a data structure (off topic; this is in tutorials), without showing us the data structure, or even giving us the code to display it.  Any of these disqualifies your post.

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting the question up to your standards and thank you for taking the time out of your busy schedule to let me know. I have been watching tutorials and searching through everything all day to find a solution. Now, I see my bigger issue is learning how to ask questions better. I will spend the rest of my day doing so. I appreciate the help.